# Can't access recovery mode because I deleted everything from HD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, ssd, restore

My Macbook PRO 13 inch of 2011 is booting to a black screen, i was trying to recovery it but the original HD was failing to install the OS, so i installed in a pen drive, then i erased everything in the HD, and then i accidentally erased everything in the pen drive, so i don't have anything in the pen drive and anything in the HD. I also have a fresh SSD, but when i try to startup with this new SSD, i only see a black screen.

I already try things like:

Remove the battery cable
Press Command + Option + R + P
Press Command + OPtion + R
Press the power button 10 seconds
Press the power button 30 seconds

Also, before the black screen, i see this lines like old television, it is fast, but they always appear. Perhaps the problem could be the screen?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried booting into internet recovery mode?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by NoahL - use internet recovery mode.

> First, check this: [Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X
>   Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904). If you can use Network Recovery, then do the
>   following:
>
> **Install OS X Using Internet Recovery**   Be sure you backup your files to an external drive or second internal drive because the
>   following procedure will remove everything from the hard drive.
>
> **Boot to the Internet Recovery HD:**   Restart the computer and after the chime press and hold down the COMMAND-OPTION- R keys until a globe
>   appears on the screen. Wait patiently - 15-20 minutes - until the
>   Recovery main menu appears.
>
> **Partition and Format the hard drive:**   Select Disk Utility from the main menu and click on the Continue button. After DU loads select
>   your newly installed hard drive (this is the entry with the mfgr.'s ID
>   and size) from the left side list. Click on the Partition tab in the
>   DU main window.
>
> Under the Volume Scheme heading set the number of partitions from the
>   drop down menu to one. Click on the Options button, set the partition
>   scheme to GUID then click on the OK button. Set the format type to Mac
>   OS Extended (Journaled.) Click on the Partition button and wait until
>   the process has completed. Quit DU and return to the main menu.
>
> **Reinstall OS X:** Select Reinstall OS X and click on the Continue button. Be sure to select the SSD.   Note: You will need an active
>   Internet connection. I suggest using Ethernet if possible because it
>   is three times faster than wireless.
>
> This should restore the version
>   of OS X originally pre-installed on the computer.